# How to customize file input in react.js

Tags: html, css, reactjs

[This is the image I need as a output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9C6t8.jpg) can anybody let me know any solution to this. Here I want the file path to display in place of "set output path" I have already given the css to the button and its uploading the file but I need the path or file name at the place of "set output path"

```
Function DataExtractor(){
const uploadFiles=()=>{
document.getElementById('selectFile').click()
}
return(
<div>
<label>Set Output Path:</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Set output path">
</div>
<div>
<button className="btn-1" onClick={uploadFiles}>Browse path</button>
<input type="file" id="selectFile" style={{display:"none"}}/>
</div>)}
)}
export default DataExtractor
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the file name as `e.target.files[0]` in `onChange` function. Something like this:

```
function DataExtractor() {
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState('')

  const uploadFiles = () => {
    document.getElementById('selectFile').click()
  }

  const handleFileChange = (e) => {
    setSelectedFile(e.target.files[0])
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <label>Set Output Path:</label>
        <input value={selectedFile} type="text" placeholder="Set output path">
      </div>
      <div>
        <button className="btn-1" onClick={uploadFiles}>Browse path</button>
        <input type="file" id="selectFile" style={{display:"none"}} onChange={handleFileChange} />
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```